# pass argument to ReactJS ES6 class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, parameter-passing, es6-class

I have one React ES6 class, containing a securityId property:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './EditParticipant.scss';

class EditParticipant extends React.Component {

    constructor(props : any, context: any) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            securityId: '1234'
        };

        this.onChangeSecurityId = this.onChangeSecurityId.bind(this);
    }

    onChangeSecurityId(newSecurityId: string) {
        this.setState({
            securityId: newSecurityId
        });
    }

    render() {

        return (
              <div>
                  Edit Participant : {this.state.securityId}
              </div>
       );
    }
};

export default EditParticipant;
```

I want to call this class from another component and pass an argument. The argument comes from URL

```
function GetEditParticipant({ match }: any) {
    var mystate = {
        securityId: match.params.securityId.toString()
    };

    return <EditParticipant state={mystate}/>;
}
```

I get an error when calling the class, at **state={mystate}**.

thanks for any help

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You must change ```EditParticipant``` to get securityId from ```props``` in constructor then set it in your ```EditParticipant's state```

Comment: You don't do anything with `props`.

Comment: Property 'state' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<EditParticipant>

Comment: You maybe meant to do -> `this.state = props.state || securityId: '1234'}`

Comment: and how to pass the match.params.securityId argument?

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend that instead of passing the value with the `state` being the key , use a proper keyname convention so that you do not get confused later on

ex :

```
return <EditParticipant securityObj={mystate}/>;
```

In the EditParticipant Component you need to do below in Constructor

```
constructor(props : any, context: any) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
        props.securityObj || {securityId: '1234'}
    };

    this.onChangeSecurityId = this.onChangeSecurityId.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. I used something else. thanks anyway